# Proof of the root test using supremum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to prove one of the cases of the root test using supremes, this is

if $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\sup \sqrt[n]{a_{n}} < 1$ then the series $\sum \{ a_{n}\}$ converges from where $\{ a_{n}\}$ is no negative and bounded.

I think that this is the way. Suppose that $L=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sup \sqrt[n]{a_{n}} < 1$ then by property of infimum approximation for $L<r<1$ there exists $n_{0}\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t.

$$L\leq U_{n_{0}}<r<1$$

because i think that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(\sup_{a_{n}})=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}(\sup_{k \geq n} {a_{k}})=\inf_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(\sup_{k \geq n} (a_{k}))$

from where $U_{n}=\sup_{k\geq n} \sqrt[k]{a_{k}}$

For $n \geq n_{0}$ we can have that

$$U_{n}\leq U_{n_{0}}<r<1$$

in particular

$$\sqrt[n]{a_{n}} \leq U_{n}\leq U_{n_{0}}<r<1$$

So

$$a_{n} \leq r^{n}$$

Since $r<1$ then the geometric series $\sum r^{n}$ converges, and by comparision test we have that $\sum a_{n}$ converges.

I have many doubts about the way I am writing the proof, please tell me if there are mistakes how can I correct them and how can I improve the writing. Thank you!

Comment: You may want to *define* $r$ (not just use the letter), e.g. as the mid point between $L$ and $1$, so $L<r<1$. We have$$\inf_N\sup_{n\ge N}a_n^{1/n}<r\ .$$An $\inf$ is thus strictly smaller than $r$. So there exists such an $N$, you call it $n_0$ with the corresponding term being below $r$:$$\sup_{n\ge n_0}a_n^{1/n}<r\ .$$In particular $$a_n^{1/n}<r$$ for all $n\ge n_0$, and thus splitting the series in the finite sum up to $n_0$, and the series starting in $n_0$ - which is dominated by $\sum _{n\ge n_0}r^n<\infty$...